# C# create an equation with Variables and If statement

Tags: c#, equation

I'm trying to have the user enter their information, and the program will take the info and find your BMI. I'm having trouble with my equation and if statement. I can't seem to find where my issue is.

```
 double _bmi = (_poundsVal / (_inchesVal * _heightVal)) * 703;


  if (_bmi <= 18.5)
  {
  Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is" + _bmi.ToString() + "you are considered underweight");
  }
  else if (_bmi > 18.5 && _bmi <= 24.9)
  {
  Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + _bmi.ToString() + "you are considered normal weight");
  }
  else if (_bmi <= 25 && _bmi <= 29.9)
  {
  Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is" + _bmi.ToString() + "you are considered overweight");
  }
  else 
  {
  Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is" + _bmi.ToString() + "you are considered obese");
  }
```

Comment: There's no reason to try to parse `_bmi`, and it probably shouldn't be an `int`.

Comment: Now that you've switched from `int.Parse` to `double.TryParse` (from your last question), what's the expectation if parsing fails? Right now, it ends up being `0.0` but if parsing fails, shouldn't you be testing that and letting the user know of the mistake? In other words, you changed two things (data type and parsing mode) but only accounted for the effects of one.

Comment: Well, where **is** your problem? Do you get an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: @HimBromBeere currently, it is saying _bmiVal doesn't exist

Comment: well, you have doubled underscore `Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is" + __bmiVal + ...);`. Seems like a simply typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_bmi should be a `double` not an `int`. change this line:

```
int _bmi = (_poundsVal / (_inchesVal * _heightVal)) * 703;
```

to

```
double _bmi = (_poundsVal / (_inchesVal * _heightVal)) * 703;
```

secondly as _bmi is a double, you don't need to Parse it, so remove this if and just keep its content:

```
if (double.TryParse(_bmi, out _bmiVal))
```

Comment: I made the changes you said above, but I'm still having an error with _bmiVal

Comment: yes as you have the answer in the _bmi, just use the _bmi in your if conditions and actually you can remove the _bmiVal

Comment: yes, as _bmi has the answer, there is no point having the _bmiVal also.

Comment: ok changed it and the only error I'm getting is from this type of line ("Your BMI is " + __bmi+ "you are considered normal weight"); It is saying _bmi doesn't exist

Comment: of course your variable is _bmi not __bmi (single underline) ;) and do it like: `Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is" + _bmi.ToString() + ...);` or `Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is {0}" , _bmi);`

Comment: Thanks! In the last line, "else (_bmi > 30)" it is saying it should be "else (_bmi > 30);" but then it gives me another error for _bmi > 30

Comment: well else does not need any condition as it mean if non of the above conditions were true, change `else (_bmi > 30)` to `else`. and you are welcome